# What is the use of creating multiple IAM users on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is the difference between root users and IAM users and for a software engineering department with multiple SWE, how should the manager handle AWS

Comment: Root has some special permissions above IAM full administrator - but they are very rarely used. Using IAM policies takes some thought, but provides fine grained access control. The answer to your question depends on your goals, your investment, how much you trust your SWE's? Also consider: AWS supports federated users/SAML - can you manage access with an existing system? Search `AWS Organizations` - you can create multiple child accounts (per user/environment/product etc) to provide logical separation and control billing and access from the parent account. Edit your question and add detail

Comment: If you are the only person who is ever going to use the AWS Account, then feel free to use the Root account. However, as soon as somebody else (or even an application you have written) needs to access AWS, you will want to be able to limit the permissions that have been granted. It's like the difference between sharing a photo from your phone with another person vs giving them access to _everything_ on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different types of users in AWS. You are either the account owner (also known as the root user), or you are an IAM user.

There is only one root user. The root user is [required for certain operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html#aws_tasks-that-require-root), including:

- changing account settings
- changing your support plan
- closing the AWS account

You should [not use the root user for everyday tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#lock-away-credentials).

For a team of software developers, you could assign each person an IAM user but it is better to use [identity federation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#bp-users-federation-idp) which gives them short-term credentials as needed.

See [IAM best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) for a lot more details.